# Can scorpion venom be used to help to identify cancer cells?

Tags: medical-science, cancer

[Apple Balla](http://www.appleballa.com/2014/07/154407/scorpions-venom-can-make-cancer-cells-glow) reports that Wired reports that scientists report that:

> Washington, July 7 (IANS) In what can alter the course of cancer treatment in the near future, researchers have found a compound that appears to pinpoint all of the malignant cells in a patient's body.
>
> The twist is that the compound's main ingredient is a molecule that is found in the sting of a deadly scorpion.
>
> The compound called chlorotoxin is found in the venom of the death stalker scorpion known as leiurus quinquestriatus.

Is it true that a venom from this scorpion can help to identify cancer cells?

Comment: The article claims it is in Phase I trials, which means nobody, not even the researchers, know whether this actually works yet. I guess answers will have to limit themselves to whether or not this is a legitimate trial in progress, and whether Apple Balla's report of the Wired report of the press release of the scientists' claims are accurate.

Comment: The article you are linking to seem to quote quite old knowledge. The Wikipedia article on chlorotoxin links to several newer studies on the same subject.